# Printing HTML Attritbutes with jquery in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, parse-platform

i try to loop trough Objects in a Database (parse.com) and would like to print these results with attributes from Bootstrap. I'm a beginner and don't understand why it's not possible how i did it. i know there is  `.attr()` but i don't get it how i can use this in my example.

This is my code:

```
    var Insider = Parse.Object.extend("Insider");


          function getPosts() {
            var query = new Parse.Query(Insider);
            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var output = "";

                    for (var i in results) {
                        var name = results[i].get("name");
                        var catego = results[i].get("cate");
                        var imageurl = results[i].get("image");  
                        var tpp = results[i].get("tipp");

                            output += "<ul class="media-list">";
                            output += "<li class="media">";
                            output += "<div class="media-left">";
                            output += "<a href="#">";
                            output += "<img id = "two" class="media-object"
alt="...">"

output += "<h4>+ + name + "</h4>";                            
output += "</a>"
                            output += "</div>"

                    }

                    $("#list").html(output);
                }, 

                error: function(error){
                    console.log("Query error:" + error.message);
                }
            });
          }
                getPosts();

    });
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The issue is due to the double quotes within the string. You need to either escape them, or use a single quote (`'`) to delimit the string itself.

Comment: also you are assignign the same id to each img tag your for loop will create. Change it to a class or make it each time a different id

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes this is also a problem, thank you. Can you tell me how it's possible to assign each time a new ID? Because now there is in each list item the same image from the query.

Comment: then change the id to a class

Comment: @LelioFaieta two classes in one image tag is possible?